# Spotfire IF statement not working when including date functions

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, case, spotfire

I am trying to convert an excel formula for use in spotfire.

In excel `=IF(MONTH(A1294)<>MONTH(B1294),(EOMONTH(A1294,0))+1,"")`

For context `=IF(MONTH(Start Time)<>MONTH(End Time),(EOMONTH(Start Time,0))+1,"")`

In Spotfire I have a calculated column and I am trying to use the following code but receiving an error "Invalid type for Function call 'If'"

My code is as follows:

```
case when Month([START_TIME_LOCALTIME])!= Month([END_TIME_LOCALTIME])
then Date(Year([END_TIME_LOCALTIME]),Month([END_TIME_LOCALTIME]),1)
else ''
END
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was because I was looking at different data types, which excel accepts but i required to use `Null` and convert to the same data type

Comment: This is because NULL != "". In fact NULL != NULL. It's the absence of a value and thus is only checked with IS NULL or IS NOT NULL